# python regex split on repeating character

Tags: regex, python-2.7, split

I have a string for example

```
--------------------------------
hello world !
--------------------------------
world hello !
--------------------------------
! hello world
```

and I want to be able to split the lines on the hyphens, the hyphens could be of variable length which is why I decided to use regex, the information I want to extract out of this is `['hello world !', 'world hello !', '! hello world']`  I have tried splitting the string using static number of hyphens, this works but not sure how to go about it if it was of variable length.  I have tried doing:

```
re.split(r'\-{3,}', str1)
```

however that did not seem to work

Comment: How did it fail to work? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/eH8gU5/1)

Comment: `[x for x in (x.strip() for x in re.split(r'-{3,}', str1)) if x]`

Comment: Or `[line for line in s.splitlines() if not re.match('-+', line)]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why did you escape `-` in your demo? *(like this `\-`)*. I think dash doesn't need to be escape.

Comment: @Shafizadeh: I am not escaping anything, OP does. It is *OP's regex demo* to show that it actually splits the string and the result is quite close. Now, the point is that OP does not mention what problem there is with the current approach, and it is most probably the whitespace and empty elements in the array. However, it should be all mentioned in the question.

Comment: @MarounMaroun that almost achieved what I wanted, however I think because I did not explain properly, I have updated the scenario and output that I want.  Thanks

Comment: Check [this demo](https://ideone.com/2SH5vN). Note: when you write *that did not seem to work* you should clarify what is wrong with the code, otherwise, we do not know what exactly fails and how we can help you best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may strip the unnecessary whitespace from the input and resulting split chunks with a `.strip()` method:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?m)^-{3,}$')
t = "--------------------------------\nhello world !\n--------------------------------\nworld hello !\n--------------------------------\n! hello world"
result = [x.strip() for x in p.split(t.strip("-\n\r"))]
print(result)
```

As for the regex, I suggest limiting to the hyphen-only *lines* with `(?m)^-{3,}$` that matches 3 or more hyphens between the start of line (`^`) and end of line (`$`) (due to `(?m)`, these anchors match the line boundaries, not the string boundaries).

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/2SH5vN)